# Joint PDF to CDF

Tags: probability-distributions

So I have this joint PDF:
$$
f(x,y)=
\begin{cases}
4xy & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1\\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
$$

To make this a CDF, I have tried to double integrate the PDF from $-\infty$ to $x$, $-\infty$ to $y$.

$$
F(x,y)= 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if } x<0\ \text{or}\ y<0\\
 x^2y^2 & \text{ if } 0 \leq x\leq1,0 \leq y\leq1 \\
? & \text{ if } 0 \leq x\leq1,y>1\\
? & \text{ if } 0 \leq y\leq1,x>1\\
1 & \text{ if } x>1,y>1
\end{cases}
$$

Can someone help me understand exactly what to do for the cases with the question marks? I am unsure of which function to apply the double integral to in order to obtain the result.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

An example:
$$F(\tfrac13,2)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}[x\leqslant\tfrac13,y\leqslant2]\,4xy\,[0\leqslant x\leqslant1,0\leqslant y\leqslant 1]\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
that is,
$$
F(\tfrac13,2)=\iint_{\mathbb R^2}[0\leqslant x\leqslant\tfrac13,0\leqslant y\leqslant1]\,4xy\,\mathrm dx\mathrm dy,
$$
and, finally,
$$
F(\tfrac13,2)=\left.x^2\right|_{x=0}^{x=1/3}\cdot\left.y^2\right|_{y=0}^{y=1}=\left(\tfrac13\right)^2$$
Thus, your $?$ are $x^2$ and $y^2$ respectively.

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align}f(x,y) &=
\begin{cases}
4xy & \text{ for } 0 \leq x \leq 1, 0\leq y \leq 1\\ 
0 & \text{ otherwise}
\end{cases}
\\[2ex]F(x,y)&= 
\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if }& x<0\text{ or }y<0\\
4\int_0^x \int_0^y st~\mathrm d t~\mathrm d s & \text{ if }& 0 \leq x\lt 1~,~0 \leq y\lt 1 \\
4\int_0^x \int_0^1 st~\mathrm d t~\mathrm d s & \text{ if }& 0 \leq x\lt 1~,~1\leq y\\
4\int_0^1 \int_0^y st~\mathrm d t~\mathrm d s & \text{ if }& 1\leq x\qquad~,~0 \leq y\lt 1\\
4\int_0^1\int_0^1 st~\mathrm d t~\mathrm d s & \text{ if }& 1\leq x\qquad~,~1\leq y
\end{cases}
\\[1ex]&=\begin{cases}
0 & \text{ if }& x<0\text{ or }y<0\\
x^2y^2 & \text{ if }& 0 \leq x\lt 1~,~0 \leq y\lt 1 \\
x^2 & \text{ if }& 0 \leq x\lt 1~,~1\leq y\\
y^2 & \text{ if }& 1\leq x\qquad~,~0 \leq y\lt 1\\
1 & \text{ if }& 1\leq x\qquad~,~1\leq y
\end{cases}
\end{align}$$